# Разный текст в плейсхолдерах для поиска меток и участников

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

Участники: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. И там, и там нужно оставить или "фильтровать", или "фильтрации".
2. И там, и там нужно оставить или "по имени", или по типу: в случае меток "по метке", а в случае участников "по участнику".